# When to clear a vertex buffer object

Tags: opengl, vbo

I'm just wondering: when (and maybe how) to clear the data from a VBO. Do you have to clear it always before rewriting the data? Why clear it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearing the buffer (i.e. setting each byte to 0) isn't too useful. *Invalidating* the buffer is.

Invalidating a section of a buffer means that the contents of that section become invalid, and you must write new content to that section before using it. This allows the OpenGL implementation to avoid waiting until the buffer object is no longer being used in order to upload data to it by giving you a completely 'new' buffer to write to (under the same name). This technique is called *buffer orphaning*.

To invalidate a buffer, you can either call `glBufferData` with the same size and usage hints, but with a `NULL` data pointer, use `glMapBufferRange` with the `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT`, or `glInvalidateBufferData` if your GPU supports it.

The [OpenGL Wiki article for Buffer Object Streaming](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) covers this in more detail, and also offers several other solutions.

To directly answer your question, it is not required that you invalidate or clear a buffer before updating it. You can call `glBufferSubData` whenever you want to update whatever contents you want. However, doing so without invalidation may cause a pipeline stall as OpenGL waits for the buffer to finish being used before safely updating it.

Comment: For people looking for a modern approach, consider functions like glClearNamedBufferSubData